# Error:'class MainWindow' has no member named 'insertMessage'

Tags: c++, qt

I am writing a SQLite database for client server program.

I wrote insert message function in myserevr.cpp like this:

```
void myserver::insertMessage(QString IPAddrress, QDate date, QString message)
{
    QSqlQuery query;

    query.prepare("INSERT INTO messages(IPAddress, date, message)"" values(?,?,?)");

    query.addBindValue(IPAddrress);
    query.addBindValue(date);
    query.addBindValue(message);
    query.exec();

    qDebug() << query.lastError();
}
```

and I call it in main.cpp like this :

```
MainWindow myserver;

bool create = QFile::exists("Message.dat");

if (!myserver.createConnection())
   return 1;

if (create)
   myserver.insertMessage();
```

but I get the following error:
"Error:'class MainWindow' has no member named 'insertMessage'"

what should I do? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well , you should not use object name  while defining a member of the class instead you should use class name  .
if `insertMessage` is the function  of `class MainWindow` then you should not define it using myserver .

```
 void myserver::insertMessage(QString IPAddrress, QDate date, QString message)//wrong
```

correct definition should be like below .

```
void MainWindow::insertMessage(QString IPAddrress, QDate date, QString message)
{
    QSqlQuery query;

    query.prepare("INSERT INTO messages(IPAddress, date, message)"" values(?,?,?)");

    query.addBindValue(IPAddrress);
    query.addBindValue(date);
    query.addBindValue(message);
    query.exec();

    qDebug() << query.lastError();
}
```

Note : When you are calling inserrMessage , you should call with relevant arguments .

**This is how you should call your function .**

```
QString ip;
QDate date;
QString msg;

if (create)
       myserver.insertMessage(ip,date,msg);//no arguments given which is wrong .Pass relevant arguments .
```

Comment: Thats right, you have define the function in a wrong way .Function definition should use class name not object name ."myserver " is the object name and "MainWindow" is the class name .use class name .

Comment: Also , "insertMessage" is taking IPAddrress, date ,message as argument . You must pass those argument while calling "insertMessage ".

Comment: I wrote it as you said and call it like this:        MainWindow.insertMessage(QString,QDate,QString); but it get the error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token

Comment: Again , there are two mistaked , first you should not call using MainWindow.insertMessage(QString,QDate,QString);. Call it using myserver.insertMessage(QString,QDate,QString);

Comment: Second mistake is you should pass object of QString, QDate,QString .

Comment: I have edited my answer , please read section "This is how you should call your function " for calling the function in correct way .

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `insertMessage()` on `myserver` which is of type `MainWindow`, right? But from code which you posted, it seems that `insertMessage()` function is defined for class `myserver`. Please check whether you are calling correct function on correct object.

Also you are calling `insertMessage()` with no arguments but the definition which you provided expects two arguments. Please check this point additionally that whether you have two versions of function `insertMessage()` i.e. one in `MainWindow` and one for `myserver`.